# PyQt how to clear items in tablewidget

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I get an item's currentrow and currentcolumn.I want to clear it.But I can't find **clear()** in [QTableWidgetItem Class](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html).How can I do this?

```
def items_clear(self):
    items=self.tableWidget.selectedItems()
    row=items[0].row()
    row2=items[1].row()
    col=items[0].column()
    col2=items[1].column()
    #  how to clear items？
```

Comment: Do you want to clear the whole table or only one widget in a certain row and column?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "clear"? Do you want to completely remove those items from the table, or just remove the text they contain? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry,I didn't say my question clear .The item isn't a row or colum ,it likes **tablewideget.item(row,colum)** . I want to delete specific item' data,so I can insert new data to it.And I don't  want to remove cells.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear one specific item of data, then just use the appropriate setter method to reset the default value. So to clear the text on all selected items:

```
def items_clear(self):
    for item in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
        item.setText('')
```

If you want to clear **all** the data for an item (i.e. text, icon, font, check-state, etc), then it's probably easiest to just set a new item:

```
def items_clear(self):
    for item in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
        newitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(item.row(), item.column(), newitem)
```